# Django application not responding while running with gunicorn and wsgi

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have developed a django application and it is running fine with the manage.py, but when I am running it with below command

> gunicorn project_name.wsgi:application

Aplication started fine with link

> localhost:8000

The application has some UI buttons when clicking on those buttons it is getting stuck i.e not responding just keep waiting for next page and this problem is not happening with the

> python manage.py runserver

command.

the log output is

```
[2017-11-10 16:07:19 +0530] [2080] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-11-10 16:07:19 +0530] [2080] [INFO] Listening at: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2080)
[2017-11-10 16:07:19 +0530] [2080] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-11-10 16:07:19 +0530] [2087] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2087
[<project_name: project_name object>]
[<project_name: project_name object>]
destination_path /home/ravi/lqiDemo/project_name/media/data/2017/11/8/13/64001859
[2017-11-10 16:07:54 +0530] [2080] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2087)
[2017-11-10 10:37:54 +0000] [2087] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2087)
[2017-11-10 16:07:54 +0530] [2128] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2128
[2017-11-10 16:08:26 +0530] [2080] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2128)
[2017-11-10 10:38:26 +0000] [2128] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2128)
[2017-11-10 16:08:26 +0530] [2135] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2135
[2017-11-10 16:08:57 +0530] [2080] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2135)
[2017-11-10 10:38:57 +0000] [2135] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2135)
[2017-11-10 16:08:57 +0530] [2152] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2152
```

my wsgi file is:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Is there any solution of that?

--EDIT
when editing

> gunicorn project_name.wsgi --log-level=DEBUG

output is

```
[2017-11-10 11:33:35 +0000] [4754] [DEBUG] GET /get/file/data/
[2017-11-10 11:33:58 +0000] [4754] [DEBUG] Closing connection. 
[2017-11-10 11:33:58 +0000] [4754] [DEBUG] Closing connection. 
[2017-11-10 11:33:58 +0000] [4754] [DEBUG] Closing connection. 
[2017-11-10 11:33:58 +0000] [4754] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
```

Comment: What does "clicking on next process in application" mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I mean application has some UI buttons to go to next steps and when clicking on those buttons application kept in waiting state.